# Trying to implement matlab pwelch function in python using scipy welch

Tags: matlab, python, power-spectral-density, statistics, scipy

I am trying to port the statistics toolbox function pwelch from matlab into python, but when I am trying to implement it using scipy.signals.welch, it does not return the same results as it does in python. below is the matlab code:

```
[pxx, freq] = pwelch(icacomps(1,:), ones(1, fs), [], fs, fs);
```

fs = 100, 
icacomps(1, : ) is of size (1, 583364). 
below is my python code:

```
the_window = scipy.signal.get_window('hamming', 100)
    freqs, power = scipy.signal.welch(icacomps[0, : ],
                                     fs = 100,
                                     window = the_window,
                                     noverlap = 100 / 2,
                                     nfft = 100 * 2,
                                     axis = 0,
                                     scaling = 'density',
                                     detrend = False)
```

where 100 is my fs value. 
below is my python output:

```
shape of icacomps[0, :]: (583364,)

freqs  0 :
 (101,)

power  0 :
 (101,)

freqs:
 [ 0.   0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3.   3.5  4.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5
  7.   7.5  8.   8.5  9.   9.5 10.  10.5 11.  11.5 12.  12.5 13.  13.5
 14.  14.5 15.  15.5 16.  16.5 17.  17.5 18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.  20.5
 21.  21.5 22.  22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25.  25.5 26.  26.5 27.  27.5
 28.  28.5 29.  29.5 30.  30.5 31.  31.5 32.  32.5 33.  33.5 34.  34.5
 35.  35.5 36.  36.5 37.  37.5 38.  38.5 39.  39.5 40.  40.5 41.  41.5
 42.  42.5 43.  43.5 44.  44.5 45.  45.5 46.  46.5 47.  47.5 48.  48.5
 49.  49.5 50. ]

power:
 [0.0313 0.1294 0.2835 0.3974 0.3775 0.2687 0.1648 0.0997 0.0631 0.0421
 0.0295 0.0214 0.0159 0.0117 0.0083 0.006  0.0046 0.0037 0.003  0.0023
 0.0017 0.0013 0.001  0.0009 0.0008 0.0007 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006
 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006
 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006
 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006 0.0006
 0.0006 0.0006 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005
 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005
 0.0004 0.0003 0.0002 0.0001 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
 0.    ]
```

[image: python plot of freq and power]

below is my matlab output:

```
pxx:
    51     1

0.0204
0.2829
0.3776
0.1512
0.0646
0.0332
0.0192
0.0105
0.0064
0.0045
0.0028
0.0020
0.0016
0.0013
0.0012
0.0011
0.0010
0.0010
0.0009
0.0009
0.0008
0.0009
0.0009
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0005
0.0003
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001

freq:
    51     1

 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
```

[image: matlab freq and power]

My values are close, but I don't understand how I am not getting the same number of values and values returned. I don't know how to implement this properly, so if anybody could show me where I am going wrong, and how to have as similar as values returned in python as is in matlab, that would be great! thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using this form of pwelch in Matlab? [pxx,f] = pwelch(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs)
In that case, there are many differences from your input parameters to scipy. Firstly, you are using a rectangular window in Matlab and a Hamming window in Python. You are right in using 0 overlap for the rectangular window and f_s/2 for the Hamming one. But you are using a 100 point FFT in Matlab and a 200 point FFT in Python. I suggest using the exact same input parameters and checking what answer you get.

Comment: Thank you @orchi_d , I mistakenly thought that the hamming window was matlabs default! I changed the code to look like this as you mentioned:    the_window = scipy.signal.get_window('boxcar', the_fs)
freqs, power = scipy.signal.welch(icacomps[0, : ],
fs = the_fs,
 window = the_window,
noverlap = the_fs / 2,
 nfft = the_fs,
axis = 0,
scaling = 'density',
 detrend = False)                    and it worked! thank you!